# File uploading fails with Error "503, bad gateway"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to upload a file using a form. Whenever I try to upload using my local server, then it works well. But, when I try this on my online application, then it mostly fails with stating "Error 503, bad gateway". Don't know what's going wrong !!!
server capabilities are

```
Memory Limit:256M
Max Upload Size:512M
Max Post Size:512M
Max Exe Time:300
Max Inp Time:300
```

Kindly help me to get rid of this !!!

Here is the code

HTML Form

```
<form class="contact-form" id="upload_form" action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label><small>License Type<sup title="Necessary">(*)</sup></small></label>
                            <?php
                                $fetch_types = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `wo_license_types` WHERE `status` = 1");
                                if($fetch_types){
                                    if($fetch_types->num_rows > 0){ ?>
                                        <select name="license_type" required required="required">
                                            <?php
                                                while($type = $fetch_types->fetch_assoc()){
                                                    ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $type['id']; ?>"><?php echo $type['title']; ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <input type="text" name="license_type" value="<?php echo getPost('license_type'); ?>" placeholder="License Type">
                                    <?php }
                                } else {
                                    redirect('lessons.php');
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label><small>Chapter No<sup title="Necessary">(*)</sup></small></label>
                            <input type="text" name="chapter_no" required required="required" placeholder="Chapter No" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" title="The chapter number should only contain numbers from 0 to 9 i.e. 12">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label><small>Chapter Name<sup title="Optional">(Opt)</sup></small></label>
                            <input type="text" name="chapter_title" placeholder="Chapter Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label><small>Page No<sup title="Necessary">(*)</sup></small></label>
                            <input type="text" name="page_no" required required="required" placeholder="Page No" pattern="[0-9]{1,3}" title="The page number should only contain numbers from 0 to 9 i.e. 120">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label><small>Description<sup title="Optional">(Opt)</sup></small></label>
                            <textarea name="description" placeholder="Give brief description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label><small>Attach Audio<sup title="Necessary">(*)</sup></small></label>
                            <input type="file" name="audio" id="audio" required required="required" placeholder="Attach audio file" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label><small>Attach Picture<sup title="Necessary">(*)</sup></small></label>
                            <input type="file" name="img" id="img" required required="required" placeholder="Attach picture" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <progress id="audio_progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:100%;"></progress>
                            <small id="audio_status"></small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                            <input style="background-color: #f43f00; color: #ffffff; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" type="button" id="post_lesson_button" value="Upload Lesson" onclick="post_lesson()">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Java Script:

```
<script>
    function _(el){
        return document.getElementById(el);
    }

    function post_lesson(){
        document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = true;
        _("audio_status").innerHTML = "<span style='color: blue;'><b>Progress:</b> Posting Lesson...</span>";
        var license_type    = $("select[name='license_type']").val().trim();
        var chapter_no      = $("input[name='chapter_no']").val().trim();
        var chapter_title   = $("input[name='chapter_title']").val().trim();
        var page_no         = $("input[name='page_no']").val().trim();
        var description     = $("textarea[name='description']").val().trim();
        var img_file        = _("img");
        var audio_file      = _("audio");
        if(img_file.files.length > 0 & audio_file.files.length > 0){
            var formdata    = new FormData();
            formdata.append("http_request", "post_lesson");
            formdata.append("license_type", license_type);
            formdata.append("chapter_no", chapter_no);
            formdata.append("chapter_title", chapter_title);
            formdata.append("page_no", page_no);
            formdata.append("description", description);
            formdata.append("img", img_file.files[0]);
            formdata.append("audio", audio_file.files[0]);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php", true);
            ajax.send(formdata);
        } else {
            _("audio_status").innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error: </b>Please attach image and audio files.</span>";
            document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function progressHandler(event){
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        _("audio_progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
        _("audio_status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploading... please wait";
    }
    function completeHandler(event){
        if(event.target.responseText[event.target.responseText.length-1] == 1){
            _("audio_status").innerHTML = "<span><b style='color: green;'>Success:</b> Lesson posted successfully !</span>";
            _("upload_form").reset();
            document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = false;
            window.location.href = "add-lesson.php";
        } else {
            _("audio_status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
            document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = false;
        }
    }
    function errorHandler(event){
        _("audio_status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
        document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = false;
        console.log(event.target.responseText);
        console.log(event);
    }
    function abortHandler(event){
        _("audio_status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
        document.getElementById("post_lesson_button").disabled = false;
        console.log(event.target.responseText);
        console.log(event);
    }

</script>
```

file_upload_parser.php

```
    <?php
    require_once 'core/init.php';

    if(isset($_POST['http_request']) AND getPost('http_request') == 'post_lesson'){
        $license_type   = getPost('license_type');
        $chapter_no     = getPost('chapter_no');
        $chapter_title  = getPost('chapter_title');
        $page_no        = getPost('page_no');
        $description    = getPost('description');
        $img_file       = $_FILES["img"];
        $audio_file     = $_FILES['audio'];
        $chapter_id     = null;
        $img_upl_name   = null;
        $audio_upl_name = null;
        if(is_numeric($chapter_no) AND $chapter_no > 0 AND is_numeric($page_no) AND $page_no > 0 AND ((strlen($chapter_title) >= 3 AND strlen($chapter_title) <= 55) OR (strlen($chapter_title) == 0)) AND ((strlen($description) >= 10 AND strlen($description) <= 500) OR (strlen($description) == 0))){
            if($error_status == false){
                echo "<span><b style='color: blue;'>Progress:</b> Validating data...<br /></span>";
                $verify_license_type = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `wo_license_types` WHERE `id` = '$license_type' AND `status` = 1");
                if(!$verify_license_type OR $verify_license_type->num_rows != 1){
                    echo "<span style='color: red;'>Something went wrong with license type !</span>";
                    exit();
                }
                $verify_chapter = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `wo_license_chapters` WHERE `license_type` = '$license_type' AND `chapter_no` = '$chapter_no' AND `status` = 1");
                if($verify_chapter){
                    if($verify_chapter->num_rows == 0){
                        $add_chapter = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `wo_license_chapters` (`chapter_no`, `title`, `license_type`, `added_by`, `status`) VALUES ('$chapter_no', '$chapter_title', '$license_type', '$admin_id', 1)");
                        if($add_chapter){
                            $chapter_id = $connection->insert_id;
                        } else {
                            echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                            exit();
                        }
                    } else if($verify_chapter->num_rows == 1){
                        $chapter_id = $verify_chapter->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                    } else {
                        echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                exit();
            }

            if($error_status == false){
                $verify_page_no = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `wo_license_pages` WHERE `chapter_id` = '$chapter_id' AND `page_no` = '$page_no' AND `language` = 1 AND `status` = 1");
                if($verify_page_no){
                    if($verify_page_no->num_rows == 1){
                        $error_status = true;
                        echo "<span style='color: red;'>You have already added this page.</span>";
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Oops... an unknown error occurred !</span>";
                exit();
            }
            if($error_status == false){
                echo "<span><b style='color: blue;'>Progress:</b> Validating files...<br /></span>";
                $img_name       = $img_file["name"];
                $img_TmpLoc     = $img_file["tmp_name"];
                $img_ErrorMsg   = $img_file["error"];
                $img_Size       = $img_file['size'];
                if(!$img_TmpLoc OR empty($img_name)) {
                    echo "<span><b>Error:</b> Please browse for an image file before clicking the post button.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                if($img_Size >= 10485760){
                    echo "<span><b>Error:</b> Image file is larger than 10 MB, Please choose other file.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                $allowed_img_files  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
                $img_ext            = explode('.', $img_name);
                $img_ext            = end($img_ext);
                $img_upl_name       = uniqid() . '.' . $img_ext;
                if(!in_array($img_ext, $allowed_img_files)){
                    echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Please choose a valid image file.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                $audio_name         = $audio_file["name"];
                $audio_TmpLoc       = $audio_file["tmp_name"];
                $audio_ErrorMsg     = $audio_file["error"];
                $audio_Size         = $audio_file['size'];
                if(!$audio_TmpLoc OR empty($audio_name)) {
                    echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Please browse for an audio file before clicking the post button.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                if($audio_Size >= 125829120){
                    echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Audio file is larger than 120 MB, Please choose other file.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                $allowed_audio_files    = array('mp3', 'aac', 'wav');
                $audio_ext              = explode('.', $audio_name);
                $audio_ext              = end($audio_ext);
                $audio_upl_name         = uniqid() . '.' . $audio_ext;
                if(!in_array($audio_ext, $allowed_audio_files)){
                    echo "<span style='color: red;'><b>Error:</b> Please choose a valid audio file.</span>";
                    $error_status = true;
                    exit();
                }
                if($error_status == false){
                    echo "<span><b style='color: blue;'>Progress:</b> Uploading image file...<br /><span>";
                    $img_upl_path = "../files/lessons/imgs/".$img_upl_name;
                    if(!move_uploaded_file($img_TmpLoc, $img_upl_path)){
                        echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Failed to upload image file, please try again !</b></span>";
                        $error_status = true;
                        exit();
                    }
                    echo "<span><b style='color: blue;'>Progress:</b> Uploading audio file...<br /><span>";
                    $audio_upl_path = "../files/lessons/audios/".$audio_upl_name;
                    if(!move_uploaded_file($audio_TmpLoc, $audio_upl_path)){
                        echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Failed to upload audio file, please try again !</b></span>";
                        $error_status = true;
                        exit();
                    }
                    if($error_status == false){
                        echo "<span><b style='color: blue;'>Progress:</b> Posting Lesson...<br /></span>";
                        $audio_upl_name = array($audio_upl_name);
                        $audio_upl_name = json_encode($audio_upl_name);
                        $post_lesson    = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `wo_license_pages` (`page_no`, `description`, `img`, `audio`, `chapter_id`, `language`, `added_by`, `status`) VALUES ('$page_no', '$description', '$img_upl_name', '$audio_upl_name', '$chapter_id', 1, '$admin_id', 1)");
                        if($post_lesson){
                            echo "1";
                            exit();
                        } else {
                            echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Failed to post lesson.</span>";
                            exit();
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Failed to post the lesson.</span>";
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Failed validation</span>";
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                echo "<span style='color: red;'>Failed validation !</span>";
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $error_status = true;
            if(!is_numeric($chapter_no)){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Enter a valid chapter number.</span>";
            } else if($chapter_no <= 0){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Enter a valid chapter number.</span>";
            } else if(!is_numeric($page_no)){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Enter a valid page number.</span>";
            } else if($page_no <= 0){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Enter a valid page number.</span>";
            } else if(strlen($chapter_title) > 0 AND strlen($chapter_title) < 3){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Chapter name must contain atleast 3 characters.</span>";
            } else if(strlen($chapter_title) > 55){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Chapter name can contain maximum 55 characters.</span>";
            } else if(strlen($description) > 0 AND strlen($description) < 10){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Demo Description must contain at least 10 characters.</span>";
            } else if(strlen($description) > 500){
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Demo Description can contain maximum 500 characters.</span>";
            } else {
                echo "<span><b style='color: red;'>Error:</b> Oops... An unknown error occurred !</span>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Needs more diagnostics - does it work with a 1byte file? 1k? 1M? 500M? If file is larger than 163Mb does it always fail at the same point, 130Mb?  Does it work with one file upload but not two?  etc

Comment: I've uploaded some other files of maximum 100 mb and those were uploaded successfully. But, this file is giving me error again and agian... And now I get the error on Console.Log and it said that "lengthComputable: false" and "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR".